# Order two way table biggest to smallest

Tags: r

My current data looks like,

```
twoway <- table(df$Sex, df$Country)

        SLO  SVK  TJK  UZB
Female    3    1   16   27  
Male      0    4   13    0
```

How can I order biggest to smaller sum of female and male like,

desired output:

```
        TJK  UZB   SVK  SLO
Female   16   27     1    3
Male     13    0     4    0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
twoway[,order(-colSums(twoway))]
```